# SQLITE3 Inner Join Returning Too Many Tuples

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 4 tables in sqlite3:

```
students(student_id, student_name)
instructors(instructor_id, instructor_name)
courses(course_id, course_name)
```

and

```
enrollments(enroll_id, student_id, instructor_id, course_id)
```

With the last 3 columns having a foreign key reference to the relevant columns in the first 3 tables

When I try to do a query that shows only the student’s name, instructor’s name and course name where an enroll_id is equal to 001 for example

```
SELECT students.student_name, instructors.instructor_name, courses.course_name
FROM users, instructors, courses INNER JOIN enrollments
WHERE enrollments.enroll_id = 001;
```

I'm getting a lot of data from all tables, but not a single tuple with just the relevant enroll data assigned to enroll_id 001. Any help is appreciated

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is especially true if you are learning SQL.  Learn to write SQL correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The right way to express this query is:

```
SELECT s.student_full_name, i.instructor_name, c.course_name
FROM enrollments e JOIN
     instructors i
     ON e.instructor_id = i.instructor_id JOIN
     courses c
     ON e.course_id = c.course_id JOIN
     students s
     ON e.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE e.enroll_id = 001;
```

The use of table aliases is highly recommended.  It makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Never is a strong word. You may use comas if you confident in what you do. Sometimes it is nice and valid. Just make sure you covered all conditions you need.

Comment: @Alex . . . This is the 21st Century; `JOIN` has been in the SQL standard for over two decades.  If you want a `CROSS JOIN`, use a `CROSS JOIN`.  If you really want to use commas, switch to MS Access; it doesn't support the `CROSS JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT students.student_full_name, instructors.instructor_name, courses.course_name
    FROM users, instructors, courses, enrollments
    WHERE enrollments.enroll_id = 001
      and enrollments.student_id = users.student_id
      and enrollments.instructor_id = instructors.instructor_id
      and enrollments.course_id = courses.course_id;
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!